# Kubernetes : Failed to retrieve auth configuration for ingress

Tags: kubernetes, basic-authentication, traefik

I have a new kubernetes cluster, I installed Traefik v1.7.6 on it and enabled Traefik dashboard which is working fine.

Now I want to add basic auth on the ingress service of traefik dashboard, I followed [docs](https://docs.traefik.io/user-guide/kubernetes/#basic-authentication) :

- created a secret called `auth-traefik` from htpasswd generated file in same namespace as Traefik
- added following annotations to ingress dashboard:

  ```
  kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
  traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-secret: auth-traefik
  traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-type: basic
  ```

I can't access the dashboard anymore and got the following page: `502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.13.12`

I restarted traefik pod and there is the following log :

```
*{"level":"error","msg":"Failed to retrieve auth configuration for ingress kube-system/traefik-dashboard: failed to load auth credentials: secret \"kube-system\"/\"auth-traefik\" not found","time":"2018-12-26T23:45:59Z"}*
```

More details: Ubuntu 18.04 running on a x64 [Scaleway](https://www.scaleway.com) server. I tried a regular & MicroK8s installation, both have the same issue (I'm going on with the MicroK8s one, for now).

Traefik was installed through the latest Helm package (with default values, I only enabled the dashboard)

Comment: How and where have you created your cluster. Provide more details

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you might have created the `auth-traefik` Kubernetes secret on a different namespace from `kube-system` where it's looking for it. (Looks like the `Ingress` is defined in the `kube-system` namespace).

You can check with:

```
$ kubectl -n kube-system get secret auth-traefik -o=yaml
```

If it's not there (is it in a different namespace? monitoring? default?), then you can create it:

```
$ kubectl create secret generic auth-traefik --from-file auth --namespace=kube-system
```

Or the [ServiceAccount](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/) that your Traefik pod is using doesn't have [RBAC](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/) access to the [Secrets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/) resource in the `kube-system namespace.

Comment: It's in the correct namespace 

apiVersion: v1
data:
  traefik.auth: //EDITED//
kind: Secret
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2018-12-26T18:18:45Z"
  name: auth-traefik
  namespace: kube-system
  resourceVersion: "13753"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/secrets/auth-traefik
  uid: aeae9e53-093a-11e9-aed6-de1a3c202010

Comment: I didn't enable rbac on the cluster and left out the rbac option from traefik's helm. Traefik pod is using default serviceaccount.

Comment: Can you try accessing the creds using that service account token? Something is wrong with your permissions.

Comment: Ran a curl with serviceaccount's token on kubernetes endpoint 
 on https://xxxxxx:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/secrets/auth-traefik, got the same result as in [previous comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53938418/kubernetes-failed-to-retrieve-auth-configuration-for-ingress/53951374?noredirect=1#comment94741562_53951374)